# How to sum values based on regex value together with few other fields?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have schema containing `text` field and few other array type fields.

```
const MySchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: String,
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
  },
  firstArrayField: {
    type: Array,
  },
  secondArrayField: {
    type: Array,
  },
});
```

Previously I needed to sum values based only on one field

```
  My.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
         userId,
         secondArrayField: secondArrayField || { $exists: true },
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$firstArrayField',
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: secondArrayField ? {
          firstArrayField: '$firstArrayField',
          secondArrayField: '$secondArrayField',
        } : { firstArrayField: '$firstArrayField' },
        sum: { $sum: 1 },
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        firstArrayField: '$_id.firstArrayField',
        sum: '$sum',
      }
    },
    { $sort: { sum: -1, hashtag: 1 } },
  ])
```

It worked well. But now I need to sum also based on text field with regex search:

```
  const query = { user };
  if (secondArrayField) filter.secondArrayField = secondArrayField;
  if (text) filter.text = { "$regex": text, "$options": "i" };

  My.aggregate([
    {
      $match: query // here I changed match object
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$firstArrayField',
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: secondArrayField ? {
          firstArrayField: '$firstArrayField',
          secondArrayField: '$secondArrayField',
          text: '$text', // Here I have problem how to pass also regex
        } : { firstArrayField: '$firstArrayField' }, // Here also I need to handle if neither secondArrayField nor text passed
        sum: { $sum: 1 },
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        firstArrayField: '$_id.firstArrayField',
        sum: '$sum',
      }
    },
    { $sort: { sum: -1, hashtag: 1 } },
  ])
```